# Android issue with Skobbler SDK for offline geocoding

Tags: android, offline, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I implemented Skobbler SDK in my app to navigate offline maps. I have an issue while trying to get coordinates from an address when user is offline. Even if I have installed the package relative to the city in which I am trying to navigate, when I start multi-step search it returns empty results without the possibility to understand what I am doing wrong because there is no way to manage eventual error messages. Here is my code as reported in Skobbler docs:

```
private void searchAtCurrentLevel(long parentId, SKSearchManager.SKListLevel level) {
// get a search manager object
SKSearchManager mgr = new SKSearchManager(this);
// get a multi-step search object
SKMultiStepSearchSettings searchSettings = new SKMultiStepSearchSettings();
// set the offline package in which to search
searchSettings.setOfflinePackageCode(code);
// set list level of the search
searchSettings.setListLevel(level);
// set maximum number of results to be received
searchSettings.setMaxSearchResultsNumber(20);
// set the id of the parent in which to search
searchSettings.setParentIndex(parentId);
// set a filter for the results
searchSettings.setSearchTerm("");
// initiate the search
mgr.multistepSearch(searchSettings);
}
```

where "code" is relative to the code of the city that I am into (for example GBCITY04 for London) and parentId is -1 like shown in Skobbler's Android "How To". I also tried to enter all different listLevel values but nothing changed.

In my app, I avoided to download "Maps.json" file because I have to manage only 2 cities, Milan and London, so i download only Milan and London's maps having relative city codes (ITCITY01 and GBCITY04). Can this be the cause of my problems?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: solved, I forgot to download one of map files during map download